# How can we handle special characters like "1Â¼" which I want to display as "1¼"

Tags: go

My database contains text encoded as "1Â¼" or "Â¼" which I want to display as "¼".  The text that may contains such characters is very large.

How can we achieve this using Golang?

Comment: Starting point for anyone attempting to answer this question: The string "Â¼" is the result of a UTF8/Latin-1 mixup. The bytes C2 BC are "¼" in UTF8 and "Â¼" in Latin-1.

Comment: Might be useful: [GoLang - Persist using ISO-8859-1 charset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555819/golang-persist-using-iso-8859-1-charset) and [Reading a non UTF-8 text file in go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277933/reading-a-non-utf-8-text-file-in-go)

Answer (score 2):

As Wumpus points out, it looks like an encoding mixup. One easy way to fix it is to force-convert your strings back into utf-8 from what I assume is  ISO-8869-1 (Latin-1).

The string you have has the following **`[]rune`**`{194, 188}`.

Encoded as utf-8, has the concrete bytes **`[]byte`**`{195, 130, 194, 188}`

To get it to display correctly, you need it so that it has the correct bytes. Essentially, your string is encoding individual bytes as runes, so we need to reverse that.

```
mistaken := // Your erroneous string
correct := []byte{}
for _, r := range(mistaken) { // Range by runes
    correct = append(correct, byte(r)) // Force conversion to byte (0-255)
}
fmt.Println(string(correct)) // Should print "¼"
```

As for what might be causing this problem, are you reading in the text from your database with the correct encoding?